# Springboot starting error with Actuator - Replacement: management.endpoints.jmx.unique-names

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm new to spring/springboot. I'm trying to enable the actuator in my project to control the log level without restart the server after yml file change.

I tried enabling actuator endpoint. But I get 404 when I try to access - `http://localhost:8080/loggers/`  or `http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers`

Springboot version - `2.1.3.RELEASE`

For this, I added below build.gradle file.

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

Then, in the application.yml added below. I do not want to enable all the end points.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: loggers
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled: true
```

I receive below warn when starting the tomcat. There is no other error in the console.

```
2020-11-28 15:35:27,093 [] INFO  [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver] > Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-11-28 15:35:27,560 [] INFO  [com.my.test.Application] > Started Application in 71.458 seconds (JVM running for 103.846)
2020-11-28 15:35:27,599 [] WARN  [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.migrator.PropertiesMigrationListener] >
The use of configuration keys that have been renamed was found in the environment:

Property source 'applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]':
        Key: endpoints.jmx.unique-names
                Line: 30
                Replacement: management.endpoints.jmx.unique-names


Each configuration key has been temporarily mapped to its replacement for your convenience. To silence this warning, please update your configuration to use the new keys.
```

Am I missing anything here?

Also, I would like to know how to protect this endpoint with some credentials. I think I can use spring security to protect this endpoint, however, I don't want to impact/block other pages in the app if I integrate the spring security. How to do this?

Comment: There is something wrong with you configuration: **Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'** while you only expose loggers: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: loggers`. Note: in your example, you do not use valid yaml-format!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with you configuration: *Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'*

This should work perfectly: starting from [spring.start.io](https://start.spring.io/) with dependencies `Spring Web` and `Spring Boot Actuator`

application.yaml

```yaml
management:
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: loggers
    endpoint:
        loggers:
            enabled: true
```

DemoController

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.logging.LoggersEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ActuatorLogLevelWithoutRestartApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ActuatorLogLevelWithoutRestartApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class DemoController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActuatorLogLevelWithoutRestartApplication.class);

    private LoggersEndpoint loggersEndpoint;

    public DemoController(LoggersEndpoint loggersEndpoint) {
        this.loggersEndpoint = loggersEndpoint;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        logger.info("hello(): info");
        logger.debug("hello(): debug");
        return "Hello World";
    }

    /* only for demo purpose */
    @GetMapping("/info")
    public String info() {
        logger.info("before change info(): info");
        logger.debug("before change info(): debug");
        loggersEndpoint.configureLogLevel("com.example.demo", LogLevel.INFO);
        logger.info("after change info(): info");
        logger.debug("after change info(): debug");
        return "log level set to INFO";
    }

    /* only for demo purpose */
    @GetMapping("/debug")
    public String  debug(){
        logger.info("before change debug(): info");
        logger.debug("before change debug(): debug");
        loggersEndpoint.configureLogLevel("com.example.demo", LogLevel.DEBUG);
        logger.info("after change debug(): info");
        logger.debug("after change debug(): debug");
        return "log level set to DEBUG";
    }

}
```

You can see de the loglevel change when you hit the endpoints [debug](http://localhost:8080/debug) and [info](http://localhost:8080/info)